# como realizar transferencia de llamada

Tags: c, objective-c

Buen día, es mi primer posteo espero sepan entender. Estoy creando una App para Ios, donde necesito realizar una transferencia de llamada. Cree el botón pero me falta la funcionalidad del mismo.
Estoy en Xcode, trabajando con objetive C, lenguaje viejisimo del cual no tengo mucha idea.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que la situación que se te presenta puedas plantearla según los lineamientos del sitio y [un ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) del código que estás empleando, de lo contrario podría ser cerrada o eliminada tu pregunta, pulsa en la opción [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/524961/edit) para añadir detalles y claro, código sino es una pregunta que se solucionaría más con opiniones que en todo caso, iría en [meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: @ang3les96 meta se usa para las preguntas relacionadas con el sitio. Si una pregunta está basada en opiniones pero es sobre programación, tampoco encajaría en meta.